# Httparty - Dynamically setting base_uri for current instance only

Tags: ruby, httparty

I have the following code which dynamically sets the base_uri for all http requests.

```
class Managementdb
  include HTTParty

  def set_url(username)
    self.class.base_uri = "https://#{username}.example.com"

    # ...
  end
end
```

However I'm finding this not only sets the base_uri for the current instance, but for all other future instances of this class too.

Is it possible to set default options like the base_uri inside a method, but only for the current instance that it's being called in?

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1):

You would use `block` for this problem. I have implemented one for your need.

```rb
class Managementdb
  include HTTParty

  def set_url(username)
    self.class.base_uri = "https://#{username}.example.com"

    # ...
  end

  def get_userinfo
    wrapper do
      set_url(username)
      self.class.get('/info')
    end
  end

  def wrapper(&block)
    yield
    self.class.base_uri = nil
  end
end
```